# validation rule Either Opportunity Name field or Case Number field must be populated, but not both

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule

validation rule  : Either Opportunity Name field or Case Number field must be populated, but not both. plz help me on this

Answer (score 1):

```
AND(
  NOT(
    AND(
      NOT(ISBLANK(OpportunityName)), 
      NOT(ISBLANK(CaseNumber))
    )
  ),
  OR(
    NOT(ISBLANK(OpportunityName)), 
    NOT(ISBLANK(CaseNumber))
  )
)
```